# My sound and ALSA has gone when I installed Realtek drivers

Tags: 11.04, sound, drivers, troubleshooting

I made a confusion with some informations and I thought that I have a Realtek audio card, but in really I have an Intel 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) High Definition Audio Controller, so when I installed the Realtek High Definition Audio Codecs it made a mess with the sound-related files, resuming, in the driver's readme it says that by default it mutes every audio channel and you is supposed to use some ALSA or OSS mixer to unmute them, and was in this part I noticed I made this confusion, because I got this trying to unmute the channels:

`sudo alsamixer` returns: cannot open the mixer: No such file or directory

`sudo amixer` returns: amixer: Mixer attach default error: No such file or directory

I already reinstalled every alsa realated package and got nothing, changing Sound Preferences settings doesn't work and there isn't any instructions to how to uninstall the Realtek drivers. I know the Realtek drivers changed something related to "sdn" and "hda".

So, how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Can someone answer?

Comment: I 've got the very same trouble, after compiling and installing the HDA driver from realtek.com I definitely lost my sound system. lspci still lists my audio chip which is however not Realtek, aplay -l tells there are no audio cards found. Complete reinstall of all alsa stuff no help. Any working solution is highly appreciated.

Comment: if someone has an answer they'll post.  Patience is a virtue on this site - sometimes the answer doesnt come around very fast (and sometimes ends up coming weeks later)

Comment: After all this time, I voted to close this question. If it is not working you should file a bug report. http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug

Answer (score 2):

This is from [a post by lidex on Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10876592&postcount=11)

> Using a Terminal="Applications->Accessories->Terminal"
>
> ```
> sudo aptitude --purge reinstall linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils linux-image-`uname -r` linux-ubuntu-modules-`uname -r` libasound2
> ```
>
> **Reboot.**
>
> For a 'command not found' error simply install aptitude:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install aptitude
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The Realtek drivers sort of worked for me; it might just be that **the ALSA mixer is muted after the driver installation.** I have also encountered a funny problem in that on my laptop I think the soundcard can somehow be **muted in hardware** (there's a keyboard short-cut to toggle it.)

I had a go at using the Realtek drivers but ended up reinstalling the previous version of the kernel that I knew worked from the liveCD using chroot (a far from ideal situation to be in).

That's not to say that the Realtek drivers can't be made to work but I found them to be more hassle than they're worth.

Update: I have another issues with my sound now possibly based around competition between my soundcard and graphic card but I believe this to be unconnected as there is sound sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

With this link I take back my audio twice, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure ... after that, I gave up try to install realteak drivers. =(

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa; sudo apt-get update;sudo apt-get dist-upgrade; sudo apt-get install linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils gdm ubuntu-desktop  linux-image-`uname -r` linux-alsa-driver-modules-$(uname -r) libasound2; sudo apt-get -y --reinstall install linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils gdm ubuntu-desktop  linux-image-`uname -r` linux-alsa-driver-modules-$(uname -r)  libasound2; killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.pulse*; sudo usermod -aG `cat /etc/group | grep -e '^pulse:' -e '^audio:' -e '^pulse-access:' -e '^pulse-rt:' -e '^video:' | awk -F: '{print $1}' | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's:,$::g'` `whoami`
```